# How to create structure for Apps to later added for a HMI WPF software

Tags: wpf

I'm currently creating a HMI software using WPF to control some hardware system. One of the key goals is to create apps for this HMI software that can be installed at a later time. The idea comes is Similar to that of the iOS apps or android apps where by the apps installed can be chosen by the user.

Is there any structure that can be used in WPF to realise this.

I believe a manifest file need to be created for the main HMI software to access these newly installed apps.But what type of file system can be accessed by the main hmi software to display the newly installed apps.

Comment: For which control system are you developing this HMI?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an out-of-the box way to do that using WPF.

I have seen an example on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673701/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WPF-Window-Applicati) that showcases how a WPF application loads an executable inside a container (notepad to be exact).

What you could do us create your *hmi app store* with WPF and have several EXE file (your apps) that can either be added or removed to your display. It might get tricky if you need to implement a communication channel between the container and the running apps, that depends a bit on what you want to achieve exactly.

I hope this can get you started!